# how to update tabel when the data is change?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this script that updates new data for every 1 second but I am confused how to update the table so that it changes the data that been edited in the table.

In my script it only shows the before the data been changed.

Can anyone give me a suggestion what type of data in my html that I can use to reference to the data that been changed?

Here's my code

```
    function update_table_usermanager(){
        var old_data = []
        $('.table-data-feedback > tbody tr').each(function(){
            var d = this.id
            old_data.push(d)
        })
        $.ajax({
            url:"update_table_adduser",
            method:"GET",
            success:function(response){
                var to_dict = JSON.parse(response)
                if(to_dict.length < old_data.length){
                    for(var z = 0; z<old_data.length; z++){
                        if(typeof(to_dict[z]) == "undefined"){
                            var delete_table = $(".table-data-feedback > tbody tr[id="+old_data[z]+"]");
                            delete_table.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }else if(to_dict.length > old_data.length){
                    for(var w = 0; w<to_dict.length; w++){
                        if(typeof(old_data[w]) == "undefined"){
                            new_table = 
                            '<tr id='+to_dict[w].line_id+'>'+
                            '<td>'+to_dict[w].id+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+to_dict[w].username+'</td>'+
                            '<td>Pending</td>'+
                            '<td>'+to_dict[w].waktu_pengajuan+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+to_dict[w].line_id+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="reply" id='+to_dict[w].line_id+'>'+
                                    '<button id="confirm-btn-image"data-value='+to_dict[w].line_id+'style="margin-right:5px;"><i class=" fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Confirm</button>'+
                                    '<button id="reject-btn-image" data-value='+to_dict[w].line_id+'><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right:5px;"></i>Reject</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '</tr>'
                            $('.table-data-feedback > tbody').append(new_table);  
                            console.log(old_data)
                            button_table();                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour: stackoverflow.com/tour and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you just want to update records that have changed or do you want to replace the whole table with the new data? Can you briefly explain the logic you're using in your code. What's working and what's not working? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: only update the edited data in the table, in my script i post, it only update the new data that been add and deleted data, but for the update(edited data) i have not done it yet because i am confused what type of data i need to reference to the edited data so it update, the way my script work is that it will check the id of each data in my table if that id not in the list that append each id in table then it will append the data to the table , if it not it will not append it.